# PHP / MySQL stand-alone installer/updater script?

Tags: php, mysql, installation, auto-update, utility

I'm looking for a script that will quickly implement package install/update functionality for my framework. It should be able to do the following things:

- Must be PHP 5 compatible.
- Should be able to install and update components' files and database tables.
- Should allow defining of package dependencies and have a form of conflict resolving.
- Should allow UPDATE SQL-statements when the developer of the package provides it. (To make database alterations without losing data).
- Should be able to 'jail' an update package to a target folder.
- Should be able to define and detect different package types to apply mentioned 'jail'.
- Should provide an API to integrate it in custom backend.
- Should allow downloading of the packages, preferably over HTTP (rather than FTP or others).

I plan on using this as a stand-alone utility to easily provide updates for modular frameworks as well as custom code for our clients.

If you have recommendations of tools that are similar or used in an open source framework to base it off that would be good as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any magic tools to do this, but a couple that might help you do these tasks are Phrake and Composer.

[Phake](https://github.com/jaz303/phake) is a PHP version of Ruby's Rake util. You could use these scripts to set up your database, update files and run unit tests.

For package management you could use [Composer](https://github.com/composer/composer) to manage your dependencies (it can also download from PEAR if you depend on packages from those systems) and of course this could be incorporated into your build scripts.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'm really loving the looks of Composer. Though neither Phake nor Composer provide the database updating features I'm after. Perhaps you know of a system that does that. Preferably the programmer of the package provides and UPDATE.SQL file to upgrade from older versions besides an INSTALL.SQL file to do a fresh install.

Comment: A good example of what I mean is implemented in Drupal modules. They generate a database schema and allow for incremental additions to this base schema per version. Also providing an update function to run code  needed to update an existing database to the target version.

Comment: Reading further into the details Composer is a fitting solution. Although it seems there is no standard for DB operations when installing/updating, it is possible to implement this and re-use this for any other product that requires it. Other than that it implements all the requirements I listed. I will accept now, thank you!

Comment: Hi, sorry I've been offline for a bit. I had a look for 'just-add-config' solutions to manage the database but came up short (although I ended up getting a lot of pages on installing PHP/MySQL, sigh). I haven't seen how Drupal does it, but theirs or Wordpress' upgrade mechanism would be worth borrowing from. I think MediaWiki has something similar too. Do update this if you find a packaged solution for this!